# How to concatenate a string and a list?

Tags: string

I would like to concatenate a string (e.g. "abc") and a list (e.g. '(aa bb)) so as to obtain "abc aa bb".

Comment: I have tried `(let ((some_list '(aa bb))) (cons "abc " some_list))` but it returns `("abc " aa bb)`

Comment: what are `aa` and `bb`? symbols will be `'aa` and `'bb`. strings will be `"aa"` and `"bb"`. are they vars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK the canonical way to turn a list into a string is with `mapconcat`, e.g.

```
(defun concat-string-list (str xs)
  (concat str " "
          (mapconcat #'symbol-name xs " ")))
```

Comment: Why `#`? is not it a symbol?

Comment: `M-x elisp-index-search RET #' RET`

Comment: why do I get `mapconcat: Wrong type argument: symbolp, "my string"` but works with `eval` ? it's lexical binding?

Comment: @Muihlinn: No.  [ Given the lack of details you give, I can't give much more details either.  ]

Comment: oh, just realized that it's a list of symbols, not a list of strings as I thought first and couldn't see beyond that for a while..

Answer (score 3):

Does the content of the list always consist of symbols like that?  If you just want the string representation of the content of the list (i.e. the printed list without the parens) you could do something like:

```
(let* ((my/str "abc ")
       (my/list '(aa bb)))
  (concat
   my/str
   (substring (format "%s" my/list) 1 -1)))

;; "abc aa bb"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method that assumes the list always contains symbols. It uses `#'symbol-name` to convert each symbol to a string.

```
ELISP> (defun string-and-list-separated-by-space (string lst)
  (string-join (cons string
                     (mapcar #'symbol-name
                             lst))
               " "))
string-and-list-separated-by-space
ELISP> (string-and-list-separated-by-space "abc" '(aa bb))
"abc aa bb"
```